# how to update an object of an element in array in mongodb?

Tags: node.js, arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query

This is the structure i have, i want to update the nested array element if an object key matches for example - i want to match grnno :"10431000" and update the other keys of that object like vehicle_no,invoice_no etc.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f128b8aeb27bb63057e3887"),
    "requirements" : [ 
        {
            "grns" : [ 
                {
                    "invoice_no" : "123",
                    "vehicle_no" : "345",
                    "req_id" : "5f128c6deb27bb63057e388a",
                    "grnno" : "10431000"
        },
        {
                    "invoice_no" : "abc",
                    "vehicle_no" : "def",
                    "req_id" : "5f128c6deb27bb63057e388a",
                    "grnno" : "10431001"
        }
          ]
       }
    ]
}
```

I have tried this code

```
 db.po_grn.update({
                "requirements.grns.grnno":"10431001"
            }, {
                $set: {
                    "requirements.$.grns": {"invoice_no":"test",vehicle_no:"5455"}
                }
            })
```

But this is changing the structure i have like this

```
 "requirements" : [ 
        {
            "grns" : {
                "invoice_no" : "test",
                 "vehicle_no":"5455"

            },
            "req_id" : ObjectId("5f128b8aeb27bb63057e3886")
        }
    ],
```

grns key should be array, and update should be of the particular object which matches the key "grnno". Please help me out. Thanks.

==Edit==

```
var grnno = req.body.grnno;
db.po_grn.find({
    "requirements.grns.grnno":grnno
}).toArray(function(err, po_grn) {
    console.log("po_grn",po_grn);
    if (po_grn.length > 0) {
        console.log("data.grn.grnno ", grnno);
        var query = {
             requirements: {
                $elemMatch: {
                    "grns.grnno": grnno
                }
             }
        };

        var update = {
            $set: {
                'requirements.$[].grns.$[inner].invoice_no': data.invoice_no,
                'requirements.$[].grns.$[inner].vehicle_no': data.vehicle_no,
            }
        };

        var options = {
            arrayFilters: [
                { "inner.grnno" : grnno }
            ] 
        };

        db.po_grn.update(query, update, options
        , function(er, grn) {
            console.log("grn",grn,"er",er)
                        res.send({
                            status: 1,
                            message: "Grn updated successfully"
                        });
                    }
            );
    } else {
            res.send({
                status: 0,
                message: "Grn not found "
            });
    }
})
```

Comment: Try this `$set: {  "requirements.$[].grns.$.invoice_no":"test",  "requirements.$[].grns.$.vehicle_no":"5455" }`

Comment: @Molda this didn't work well for me, it updated the 0th index, whereas it should have updated the index that matches the key, seems it is for the first index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a combination of [`$[]`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-all/) positional-all operator with [`array filters`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/#update-all-array-elements-that-match-arrayfilters) to update your inner nested document.

```
var query = {
     requirements: {
        $elemMatch: {
            "grns.grnno": "10431001"
        }
     }
};

var update = {
    $set: {
        'requirements.$[].grns.$[inner].invoice_no': "test",
        'requirements.$[].grns.$[inner].vehicle_no': "5455",
    }
};

var options = {
    arrayFilters: [
        { "inner.grnno" : "10431001" }
    ] 
};

db.collection.update(query, update, options);
```

---

Update -

NodeJS native MongoDb driver code attached, which is working fine

[image]

```
const { MongoClient } = require('mongodb');
const url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/";

MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
  if (err) {
    throw err;
  }

  const dbo = db.db("test");
  (async() => {
    const query = {
        requirements: {
           $elemMatch: {
               "grns.grnno": "10431001"
           }
        }
    };
   
   const update = {
       $set: {
           'requirements.$[].grns.$[inner].invoice_no': "test",
           'requirements.$[].grns.$[inner].vehicle_no': "5455",
       }
    };
   
   const options = {
       arrayFilters: [
           { "inner.grnno" : "10431001" }
       ],
       multi: true
   };

    try {
      const updateResult = await dbo.collection("collection").update(query, update, options);
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
    db.close();
  })(); 
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked in robo 3T, however for some reason I am getting "'No array filter found for identifier \'inner\' in path \'requirements.$[].grns.$[inner].store_grn\'' " this error when i run this in the node.

Comment: @pse are you using MongoDb 3.6+ ?

Comment: Its: db version v4.0.17

Comment: @pse Are you using mongoose or the native mongodb node js driver ?

Comment: native mongodb and my node version is v10.15.3. I tried different possibilities of your query but it's still giving the same error:-
  name: 'MongoError',
  message:
   'No array filter found for identifier \'inner\' in path \'requirements.$[].grns.$[inner].store_grn\'',
  driver: true,
  index: 0,
  code: 2,
  errmsg:
   'No array filter found for identifier \'inner\' in path \'requirements.$[].grns.$[inner].store_grn\'' }

Comment: @pse can you check db.version() in your mongo shell, you can upgrade your mongo version to 4.2 if possible

Comment: @pse what was the issue and what fix you did to run it ?

Comment: I upgraded my mongo version to 4.2 and somehow it worked for me